# Chrome Redirects gets cancelled - Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, react-native

My redirect gets canceled and I am trying to redirect to custom scheme, ie. `myapp://url`.

I have tried the following:

`window.location.assign('url);`

`window.location.replace('url')'`

`window.open('url');`

`window.location.href = 'url';`

I have even tried to make it work with `setTimeout()`, but to no avail.

Is there a way to make this work, I am trying to make clickable deeplinks in gmail?

Comment: `window.location.href = 'url');` should be `window.location.href = 'url';`. Note the wrong closing bracket.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Apologies.